# How to draw some text when click a button in wxWidgets?

Tags: wxwidgets

I want to draw some text when click a button. My code is:

```
#include <wx/wx.h>

enum
{
    BUTTON_Hello = wxID_HIGHEST + 1
};
class myFrame : public wxFrame {
public:
    wxButton* HelloWorld;
    wxPanel* panel;

    void OnPaint(wxCommandEvent& event) {

        wxClientDC bdc =wxClientDC(this);
        bdc.DrawText(wxString("Draw some text when button clicked."), wxPoint(300, 300));

        Refresh();
    };

    myFrame(wxWindow* parent,
        wxWindowID id,
        const wxString& title,
        const wxPoint& pos = wxDefaultPosition,
        const wxSize& size = wxDefaultSize) :
        wxFrame(parent,id,title, pos, size) {

        panel =new wxPanel(this, wxID_ANY, wxPoint(0,0),wxSize(100,100));
        //Connect(wxEVT_PAINT, wxPaintEventHandler(myFrame::OnPaint));
        HelloWorld = new wxButton(panel, BUTTON_Hello, _T("Hello World"),
            wxPoint(5,5), wxSize(100, 100));
        HelloWorld->Bind(wxEVT_BUTTON, &myFrame::OnPaint, this);

    };

};


class MyApp : public wxApp
{
    bool OnInit() {
        frame = new myFrame((wxFrame*)NULL, -1, wxT("Hello wxDC"),
            wxPoint(50, 50), wxSize(800, 600));
        frame->Show();
        return true;
    };

    wxFrame* frame;

public:

};

IMPLEMENT_APP(MyApp)
```

I define the drawing function in a `wxFrame` and bind it to a `wxButton` using `Bind()`. The drawing function uses a `wxClientDC`. I have added `Refersh()` to force updating `wxFrame`. The `wxButton` belongs to a `wxPanel` which is a child of `wxFrame`.

However, when I click the button, nothing happens and no text is shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **must** use `wxPaintDC` when drawing in your `wxEVT_PAINT` handler, not `wxClientDC`. While `wxClientDC` also "works", at least for now and at least under some platforms, this is definitely not the right way to do it.

When using `wxPaintDC`, `Refresh()` would work as expected and will result in a call to your paint handler during the next event loop iteration. Normally you don't need to call `Update()`, which immediately calls your handler, at all.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by myself.
As `wxPanel` is the only child of `wxFrame`, it will automatically cover the whole area of `wxFrame`. Now drawing on `wxFrame` is necessarily having no effect. So I have to draw on `wxPanel`:

```
    void paintNow(wxCommandEvent& event) {

        wxClientDC bdc =wxClientDC(panel);
        bdc.DrawText(wxString("Draw some texts when button clicked."), 
            wxPoint(300, 300));

        //panel->Refresh();
        panel->Update();
    };
```

Also I find that if I use `Refresh()` and `Update()` simultaneously, no text will be shown.

If I only use `Refresh()`, no text will be shown.

Comment: As Vadim wrote please use wxPaintDC to paint.

Comment: Also you must use both EVT_BUTTON and EVT_PAINT events. The way the code is written - everything will be erased on the next EVT_PAINT.